Error initializing webdriver in Selenium. Trying to find the cheapest tickets. How to do it?
I want to develop an application that will collect the cheapest tickets from Skyscanner for certain destinations for a certain period of dates.
There are no problems with the request, because Skyscanner receives all search data in Get. For example:
https://www.skyscanner.net/transport/flights/lond/mnl/240504/?adultsv2=1&cabinclass=economy&childrenv2=&inboundaltsenabled=false&outboundaltsenabled=false&preferdirects=false&ref=home&rtn=0
On the page we see the field where the cheapest price is indicated. However, this information is not present in the HTML. Either this is output via JS, or I was careless and didn't find it in the HTML.
Since there is dynamic content, I decided to use Selenium.
I wrote the code using the guides that I managed to find. However, during webdriver initialization, I receive an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Skyscanner\skyscanner.py", line 21, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, chrome_options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Skyscanner\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Skyscanner\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 50, in __init__
    if finder.get_browser_path():
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Skyscanner\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 47, in get_browser_path
    return self._binary_paths()["browser_path"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Skyscanner\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 56, in _binary_paths
    browser = self._options.capabilities["browserName"]
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'

Here's my code. Please give me some tips on how to fix this and achieve my goal?
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Runs Chrome in headless mode.
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

driver_path = 'C:\\chrome-win64\\chrome.exe'

url = 'https://www.skyscanner.net/transport/flights/lond/mnl/240504/?adultsv2=1&cabinclass=economy&childrenv2=&inboundaltsenabled=false&outboundaltsenabled=false&preferdirects=false&ref=home&rtn=0'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, chrome_options)

try:
    driver.get(url)
    
    time.sleep(20)

    cheapest_flight = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'FlightCard_price')]"))
    )
    
    print(f"Cheapest Flight Price: {cheapest_flight.text}")

finally:
    driver.quit()


chrome.exe is a web browser but drive_path needs file chromedriver.exe which you have to download and install on your own (if you use older Selenium). New Selenium should download driver automatically when it can't find it on computer - and you don't have to use drive_path. Other problem is that driver_path as a string was used in much older Selenium, newer versions use special class Service() for this - so it can't be string

Webpage with ChromeDriver: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/. BTW: If you would need to use Firefox then you would need to use geckodriver.exe, and for Microsoft Edge you would need msedgedriver.exe - and you would have to search them on different web pages. But the newest Selenium should download it automatically - so you  can skip drive_path

chrome.exe is a web browser but driver_path needs special program which connects Selenium with browser - driver - and for chrome it is chromedriver.exe
which you could find on chromedriver.chromium.org
For Firefox you would need geckodriver.exe,
for Microsoft Edge you would need msedgedriver.exe,
and you would have to search them on different web pages.
But ...
... string with driver_path was used directly in Chrome(...) in older versions of Selenium.
In newer versions you have to use class Service(...) with this path but as executable_path.
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(executable_path=driver_path), options=chrome_options)

But ...
... there is special module webdriver_manager which you can use in Service and it will check if you have driver and eventually it will download correct version. (because when you update browser then it may need newer driver)
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)

But ...
... in the newest version of Selenium you don't need it because it checks driver and download it automatically.
So you may need only
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)


